# Advantages and disadvantages of nesting functions

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a function that relies on another function to do computations, e.g.

```
skew_add_list <- function(a, b){

    stopifnot(length(a) == length(b))

    skew_add <- function(a,b){
        a + b + rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    }   

    result_list <- lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) skew_add(a[[i]], b[[i]]))

    return(result_list)
}
```

Now, `skew_add` is a very specific function and is only used in the body of `skew_add_list`. So, what are the advantages/disadvantages of leaving the functions as defined in the above code block, compared to splitting them out, as in:

```
skew_add <- function(a,b){
    a + b + rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
}   


skew_add_list <- function(a, b){

    stopifnot(length(a) == length(b))

    result_list <- lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) skew_add(a[[i]], b[[i]]))

    return(result_list)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One disadvantage of declaring a nested function is the fact that it will be created inside function's environment every time you call 'parent' function. This is called 'fresh start' principle. In theory, it could decrease performance if parent function is called frequently. But I highly doubt that it will be noticeable in practice.

Personally, I prefer nested function in such cases to improve code readability and to not overflow global environment.

Comment: See the benchmarks in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30425500/1412059). Performance cost of defining a function is extremely low.

Comment: Another annoying thing about nesting functions is that in Rstudio at least, when you hit collapse all (Alt-O), all nested functions get collapsed within the main function. So it's hard to see previously defined functions that you might want to generalise for use in other functions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Flame's comments about performance. But the effect can be visible only if the  the meaning computational time is low vs. code parsing time.

In my opinion, nested functions are really usefull for code readability. You can consider functions with nested functions as a kind of "module" where nested functions are making sense inside that module. More or less an object oriented method but with only static methods.

So, in short, when you use a function `f2` which will only be called by `f1`, and is only meaningfull in `f1`'s context, nest `f2` inside `f1`.

Again, only an opinion...